# what is the meaning of func(a)(**kwargs))

Tags: python

I have a code that has the pattern "function(a)(**kwargs)". I know only the pattern "function (a, **kwargs)". What does it mean if there is a second set of arguments in separate paranthesis?

Shortened to what I think is relevant the code looks like this:

## myprog1.py

```
def factory(cid, classes=CLASS_CACHE):
    some code ...
```

## myprog2.py

```
from myprog1 import factory
...

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, operations, factory):
        self.factory = factory

def some_function()
    chk = self.factory(test)(**kwargs)
```

factory is a function, test is a string (naming an object).

Answer (score 3):

`function(a)(**kwargs)` calls the returned value of `function(a)` with keyword arguments unpacked from `**kwargs`. E.g the below code

```
def f():
    def inner(**ka):
        print(ka) # print received keyword arguments
    return inner # return a callable function object

f()(argument='here')
```

outputs

```
{'argument': 'here'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clear. Short syntax, but not obvious for beginners :-/

Answer (score 2):

`**kwargs` is a syntax construction, which makes function arguments from dictionary. For example:

```
def a(b, c):
    print b + c

args = {'b': 1, 'c': 2}
a(**args)  # will print 3
```

In you code, search for definition of kwargs. I bet you `some_function` has `**kwargs` in arguments list like so:

```
def some_function(**kwargs):
```

So, your code `chk = self.factory(test)(**kwargs)` will do this thing:

1. Call `self.factory` method with `test` argument.
2. `self.factory` returns function
3. Returned function will be called with arguments, which is passed in `some_function` as arguments.